# KTUtil is not defined

Tags: javascript, .net, webforms

I am using the below function in Web Form aspx page, it was working fine, but last night I have get latest from tfs and after that I think there are some js files are missing, and I am getting this

> KTUtil is not defined

error in console, I don't have idea from where is this method defined.

```
KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded(function(){
   KTCreateAcount.init();
})
```

Please help me to sort this issue, and I am totally confused. Thank you